# Send UDP packet on TCP connected port

Tags: go, udp

I have a Golang TCP server, i.e. `net.TCPConn`, connected on a port which, in addition to a TCP stream, also has to receive UDP packets and respond with UDP packets.  The incoming UDP packet pops out at the server (from a `net.TCPConn.Read()`) but I can't figure out how to send a UDP packet back again.  All of the UDP write methods apply only to `net.UDPConn`.  `net.UDPConn.WriteMsgUDP()` tantalisingly talks of whether it is applied to a connected or a non-connected socket, but I can't figure out how to derive `net.UDPConn` from `net.TCPConn`; I've tried casting `net.TCPConn` to `net.UDPConn` but that causes a panic.

What is the correct way to do this?

FYI, I do have a UDP listener open on the same port ('cos the client at the other end can chose to operate in completely connectionless mode) but since, when the socket is connected, the UDP packet arrives at the TCP server rather than the UDP server, I'd like to send the UDP response back down the same hole, rather than having to mix the two up in some unholy manner.  Or is unholiness the answer?

EDIT: a word on the system design here: the purpose of this UDP packet is to test the connection on this socket (the server simply echoes it back).  The socket is a [hopefully] established SSH port-forwarding tunnel, hence I don't want to use another socket as this wouldn't test what I'm trying to test (i.e. that both the socket and the SSH tunnel are open; it is a shortcoming of SSH port-forwarding tunnels that, since the application makes a connection to `localhost`, the socket will report connected immediately, even if the server isn't actually connected at the time).  The SSH tunnel otherwise carries a stream of TCP traffic and I specifically want to use UDP for this as I don't want my UDP connection test to be stuck behind the queue of TCP traffic; timing is important in this application and the UDP packet carries timestamps to measure it.  [Sending a UDP packet on a connected socket](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto) is a valid sockets operation, Go must have a way to do it...?

Comment: UDP doesn't establish a connection, usually when you are working with UDP you deal with packets directly, that are addressed individually, so when receiving and sending each packet you also need to either receive or inform the peer's IP+port to know who you are talking to or from who the information came from. There are two syscalls used for that, `recvfrom()` and `sendto()`, I don't know how Go implemented this but I'm pretty sure `net.TCPConn.Read()` won't work for UDP at all.

Comment: You can’t send or receive UDP packets from a TCP connection. If you need to send UDP packets, use a UDP connection.

Comment: I know that UDP is connectionless but it is [perfectly valid sockets](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto) to send a UDP packet down a connected socket; you just leave the destination address off the `sendto()` and it figures out what you mean.  I know this because this is exactly what the other end of the link, coded in C, is doing in this case.  Surely Golang has allowed for what is a quite normal sockets operation in its `net` implementation!?  The comment in [net.UDPConn.WriteMsgUDP()](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#UDPConn.WriteMsgUDP) implies it has, I just can't figure out how it works.

Comment: You cannot send UDP packets over a TCP connection, it doesn’t make any sense. I can assure you you’re not receiving a UDP packet on the TCP connection, and since the ssh tunnel is TCP, you cannot send it a UDP packet. There might be a UDP socket listening on the same port number, but it is completely separate from the TCP connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a discussion on the [Golang forums](https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/net-pkg-sending-a-udp-packet-on-a-connected-socket/8810) all has become clear.

@JimB is quite right that you cannot send a UDP packet on a TCP port.  The reason I thought this was possible is that the definition of `sendto()` says:

> If `sendto()` is used on a connection-mode (`SOCK_STREAM`,
>   `SOCK_SEQPACKET`) socket, the arguments `dest_addr` and `addrlen` are
>   ignored (and the error `EISCONN` may be returned when they are not
>   `NULL` and 0), and the error `ENOTCONN` is returned when the socket
>   was not actually connected.

...and when I called `sendto()` on my TCP connected port the data I sent did indeed turn up at my Golang `net.TCPConn` end-point.  However, what is happening in this scenario is that, under the hood, `sendto()` has effectively become an alias for `send()` and, despite calling `sendto()`, the data sent is actually being transported in a TCP packet and not a UDP packet at all.  This was proved by using `netcat -u $host $port` to send UDP traffic to the server and `netcat $host $port` to send TCP traffic to the server: the former did not produce any data at the `net.TCPConn` end-point while the latter did.

The correct way to do this is for the client to open a TCP *and* a UDP socket to the server on the same port at the same time while the server, likewise, listens simultaneously for TCP and UDP "connections" (the UDP connection is not a connection at all of course, it is simply an association with a local port number) on the same port.  The TCP server then handles my stream and the UDP server handles my UDP test/measurement packets, both down the same SSH port forwarding tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to send a UDP packet to a "client" that first reaches your application via TCP, what probably you could is to get the remote [address](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Addr):

```
addr = net.TCPConn.RemoteAddr()
```

Then assuming this client is also a server and listening on port `UDP` in `1234`

```
ServerAddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", fmt.Sprintf("%s:1234", addr))
```

Then you could just write back by doing:

```
 conn, err := net.DialUDP("udp", nil, ServerAddr)
 if err != nil {
     log.Fatal(err)
 }
 defer close(conn)
 buf := []byte("ping")
 _, err = conn.Write(buf)
```

Don't know if this is exactly what you want but hope can give you some more ideas.